# How do you query an array in mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb

```
{
 "_id":123456,
 "Menu":[{
    "Dish":"Apple pie",
    "Rating": "Good",
    "Method": "Oven Baked"
   },

   {
     "Dish":"Pumpkin Pie",
    "Rating": "Bad",
    "Method": "Baked"
   },
   {
    "Dish":"Tomato Soup",
    "Rating": "Good",
    "Method": "Boiled"
   }]
```

}

How do I query this array if I would only like to display the values in the field "Method"?

How do I solve this with Pymongo?

Comment: You can use the `projection` in your query: http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html?highlight=projection#pymongo.collection.Collection.find

Answer (score 0):

Use the below Mongo Shell query

```
 db.mycollection.find({_id:123456}, {"Menu.Method":1})
```

This query will yield the below result on your sample document

```
{
        "_id" : 123456,
        "Menu" : [
                {
                        "Method" : "Oven Baked"
                },
                {
                        "Method" : "Baked"
                },
                {
                        "Method" : "Boiled"
                }
        ]
}
```